# Logo design issue

Tags: logo

forgive me if this question doesnt fit the purpose of this stackexchange site,
Some of you probably have experience with logo design,
I'd like to ask a question,

I currently have a client that owns a website that lets marrying couples arrange their weddings in, find suppliers such as wedding dress designers or wedding halls / gardens.

I've never had such a hard time designing a logo before,
His website is named "Marrying", not in english though.

My main problem here is that I literally can't find any creative idea other than the generic ones like Rings,hearts, love birds, etc'.

Please, I'd really be grateful to get some refreshing tips or something like that.

So yea I'd love to see your ideas and learn how to think out of the box, even when I have such a hard time.

Thanks

Comment: This question might not fit because it's a brainstorming question. Having said that, I suggest to you to not focus on the very general term of marriage but on the companys quailties. What is their philosophy? What sets them apart from the rest? What do they do better? Do they have a motto? What makes them unique? Do they offer a service others don't? Is there anything special how they do their work? Logo design is often more a research task than a design task. Hope that helps.

Comment: @KMSTR I did try to brainstorm and think about it, the thing is that nope, that site is quite identical to others, nothing too special about it. what it does? it lets people find suppliers, and the only thing I could think about now was a magnifying glass, I feel like I'm being too generic, but I don't know exactly how to change that

Comment: Logos don't have to be (and often shouldn't be) literal representations of the product or service. Play with typography. Play with the name. Work with colors. Play with adjectives rather than nouns. No need to use cliche symbols.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is not the logo. Your problem — actually your client's problem — is ***branding***.

Your client, as KMSTR noted above, has not distinguished himself from the pack. Writer and marketer Seth Godin calls this the [Purple Cow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1591843170) property. The idea is that a brand's defining property is that it is the "-est" (the most) of something: the fastest, the sleekest, the easiest to use, the roundest, the most local, the most comprehensive, whatever.

So go back to your client and brainstorm with him. Why is he establishing this company or this site? Does he want to provide one-stop shopping for marrying couples? Does he want to specialize in ethnic or culturally-experienced providers? Same-sex weddings? Religious weddings?

When the client knows what his Purple Cow is, you will have something to hang your logo on.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I see the point you've made here, I'm quite sure that what the client will tell me is that he wants it to be the easiest to use, if so, how would it help me designing the logo? what icon could represent simplicity?

Comment: He needs a tagline. "Weddings. Made Simple." Or "Unstress the Dress." I would then create a logo in very simple type, like Futura Extra Bold, Franklin Gothic No.2, or a Helvetica, with the tagline underneath. Black or gray (silver) type on white, or possibly gold on white. Maybe the dot of the I could be a diamond (like engagement ring). You won't create an icon per se, but you can create a logo out of words (logotype) which, along with the tagline, demonstrates the simplicity you want. NO script type unless it's an extremely plain chancery.

Comment: She's b-a-a-a-ck! Great to see you here again. We've missed your voice and sage advice. :)

Comment: Thank you, dear; I could say the same for you. :) I've been here every day; I just haven't had any productive answers to give.

Answer (score 1):

While I do feel this is more a brainstorming or localize question, which is off-topic according to the FAQ. I would offer some help if I can....

You're being too litteral.

Start with words.... 5 words that describe the business such as (these are quick examples):

- coupling
- connection
- romance
- life-long
- partner

Then branch out to 5 words or phrases which describe each of those words... i.e.

- Coupling

  - rings
  - pair
  - love birds
  - holding hands

etc.

In the end you have 25+ words and phrases which you can mix and match to come up with some sort of graphic.

As for the opinions of others on the artwork, it's difficult to say. Audiences vary depending upon where you ask. I've had work I though was really bad praised. And I've had work I loved literally spat upon. In the end create something you're proud to put your name on when asked.... chances are it'll be close to or exactly what the client is seeking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still find it hard to think out of the box and come up with new ideas other than the ones I already mentioned, but I'll try more I suppose